# How do I make Mui textfield type number only accept number ? Currently it accept numbers,"e" and dashes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

**This is my current code.**

```js
<TextField error={values[1].error} fullWidth id="id" type="number" value={values[1].Id} placeholder='Enter ID' onChange={handleChange(1,'Id')} variant="outlined" inputProps={{min: 0,inputMode: 'numeric', pattern: '[0-9]'}} onBlur={() => handleOnBlurEvent(1,'Id')} />
```

Comment: E.g. `-1e2` is a valid number.

Comment: thats becoz e is for exponential, if you want to restrict it then probably you need to have a custom validation using keyup or keydown

Comment: can you please suggest any documentation to restrict e and dashes?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by *jonrsharpe*, numbers containing `-` or `e` are still valid numbers.

If you still want to limit the changes that are being accepted, you can make use of a custom `handleNumberChange` function that filters chars such as `e`, `E` and `-`.

```
const handleNumberChange = (id: number, key: string, value: string) => {
  if (["e", "E", "-"].some((char) => value.includes(char))) return;

  // handle change here
};
```

You would use it like that in your MUI `<TextField/>`:

```
<TextField
  ...
  onChange={(e) => handleNumberChange(1, "Id", e.target.value)}
/>
```